# Time operations in ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, time

I am new to ruby. I am trying to calculate the number of seconds for a given period. I have a start time and end time with HH:MM:SS format.

Can I declare a variable as object of Time class and perform calculations?
Example:

```
start_time='15:00:12'
end_time='19:32:12'
a=Time.new(start_time)
b=Time.new(end_time)
duration_seconds=a-b
```

Comment: The operations exist, but that's not how you generate a timestamp in Ruby.  Were you looking for something that didn't consider what *day* it was, or were you going to use `Time`?

Comment: I am only interested in time, preferably in seconds

Comment: `Time` has an expectation that a day is supplied to it, or it defaults to January 1.  Do you care about that in your operations?

Comment: The date is highly relevant here. Some days have 23 hours, others 25, so it's impossible to know how many hours have elapsed between those two times without that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code in Ruby

Since Time.new expects parameters like year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds - I have used current time for first 3 parameter, and the values from the string parameter that OP had for rest of 3 parameters

Getting difference between the two time - I have used `to_i` method which returns number of seconds from Epoch that `Time` instance represents

```
string_start_time ='15:00:12'
start_time_parts = string_start_time.split(":").collect{ |y| y.to_i }
start_time = Time.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day, start_time_parts[0], start_time_parts[1], start_time_parts[2])
p start_time

string_end_time='19:32:12'
end_time_parts = string_end_time.split(":").collect{ |y| y.to_i }
end_time = Time.new(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day, end_time_parts[0], end_time_parts[1], end_time_parts[2])
p end_time

p duration_seconds = end_time.to_i - start_time.to_i
```

**NOTE:** Some code refactoring is needed to extract a function to create time from HH:MM:SS, I have duplicate code

Output of above code will be

```
2015-07-14 15:00:12 +0530
2015-07-14 19:32:12 +0530
16320
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: This looks similar to the implementation of `Time.parse`. Why repeat?

Comment: @NicNilov  I did not find parse method in Ruby Doc - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html   I am new to Ruby as well so just worked on this problem and came up with this

Comment: It is in [standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) and not the core where you were looking. [See here for the difference between the core and stdlib](https://h3rald.com/ruby-compendium/book/core-stdlib.html)

Comment: Thanks @NicNilov for the pointers.  I understood that based on others answers

Answer (score 1):

You came pretty close, this code does that:

```
start_time = '15:00:12'
end_time = '19:32:12'
a = Time.parse(start_time)
b = Time.parse(end_time)
duration_seconds = a - b
```

The `Time.parse` method converts string to a `Time` instance. It understands some but not all formats a time string can have so you'd probably want to validate the input. See [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) for more details.

Comment: You're missing the part where you have to `require 'time'`.  Without that, a Ruby beginner won't see the same results you are.

Comment: Since the code in question does not have `require 'time'` and there is no reference to an error it's reasonable to assume OP got this part right. Are you sure this omission really warrants the `-1`?

Comment: Well, try it in a terminal.  I'm no Ruby expert, but I would be very surprised if I were to take your code on faith, execute it, only to see a `NoMethodError` pop up.

Comment: Further, the documents that you linked to even go as far as to mention that this particular module *must* be required.

Comment: Well my answer refers to the documentation doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing

```
require "time"
start_time='15:00:12'
end_time='19:32:12'
Time.new(2002,1,1,*end_time.split(":")) - Time.new(2002,1,1,*start_time.split(":"))
```

I assume that you want to know time in the same day.
And I put the END - START to get positive values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
end_time=Time.strptime('19:32:12',"%H:%M:%S")
start_time=Time.strptime('15:00:12',"%H:%M:%S")
end_time-start_time
```